# CodeBloks C++ Error: Was not declared in the scope

Tags: c++

Hey guys I'm trying to learn C++ and I was doing pretty well until I hit this wall..

I am getting two errors:
error: 'enter' was not declared in this scope
error: 'Satisfies' was not declared in this scope|

Here is my file. Why is that?

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (1){
        char menu;
        cin>>menu;
        switch (menu){
            case 1: Enter(); break;
            case 2: Satisfies(); break;
            case 3: break;
            };
    };
}

int Enter(){
    return 0;
}

int Satisfies(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function calls need `()`, eg `Enter();`. Also free functions must be declared before they are used, so above `int main()`

Comment: It's hard to tell with that formatting. But for starters move your helper functions above the main, or declare their prototypes above main.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the functions before their usage for example before main and use the correct syntax of calling functions.

For example

```
//...
int Enter(){ return 0; }

int Satisfies(){ return 0; }
//...
int main()
{
//...
case 1:
   Enter();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *declare* the functions before they are used. So put this above `main`:

```
int Enter();
int Satisfies();
```

You can leave the *definitions* (the bit that actually contains the code to run when the function is called) where they are. Or you can just move those functions above `main`, since a function *definition* is also a *declaration*.

The compiler needs to see these bits before it tries to call the function, so that it can know what arguments it needs, and what will be returned.

[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410563/1171191)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare (or declare and definite) a function before you use it. And you need to make function calls with (). Like Enter() and Satisfied(). If you want to learn good programming and C coding and then go to C++ read "C for Dummies" by Dan Godkin. My favourite coding book.

You have 3 ways to do this and fix your code:

**1. Write prototy definitions:**

```
#include <iostram>

int Enter();
int Satisfies();


using namespace std;

int main() 
{  
   //bla
}

int Enter(){ return 0; }
int Satisfies(){ return 0; }
```

**2. Make a function.h file and put the declarations there. Save it in the same folder as the c / cpp file**

then include in your code

```
#include "function.h"
```

**3 Put your functions in order of execution in the c/cpp file. A function must be declared before it is used. Example:**

```
void Enter()
{
  //bla
}

void Satisfied()
{
  //blub
}

int main() 
{
 Enter();
 Satisfied();
}
```

More tricky example, when a function (Satisfied) uses an other function (Enter) the Enter function must be declared before the  Satisfied function:

```
void Enter()
{
  //bla
}

void Satisfied()
{
  //blubb
  Enter(); //now Enter must be declared before is Satisfied() is defined, so it must be "over" it in the source like in this example
}

int main() 
{
 Enter();
 Satisfied();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function call need to have `()` after the function name doesn't matter whether it take any parameter or not. Plus you need to define function header before `main()`

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Enter();
int Satisfies();

int main() {
    while (1){
        char menu;
        cin>>menu;
        switch (menu){
            case 1: Enter(); 
                break;
            case 2: Satisfies(); 
                break;
            case 3: 
                break;
        };
    };
}

int Enter(){
    return 0;
}

int Satisfies(){
    return 0;
}
```